# Wind patterns on a tidally locked planet (one side always faces the sun)

Tags: wind, planetary-science, world-building

I'm moving this question from Worldbuilding StackExchange ([Link](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/252919/wind-patterns-on-a-tidally-locked-planets-contradict-my-logic-looking-for-corre)). I know it's not strictly about Earth, but I'm hoping it will still be accepted here since it's related to meteorology. Here we go:

---

My take on the wind patterns on a tidally locked planet (TDL) does not lead to the information given in papers and videos. Please tell me where I went wrong.

**My take:**

On a TLP, the sub-solar point is a region of low air pressure (due to its high temperature), while the night side has relative higher air pressure. Wind flows from high to low air pressure, resulting in a wind pattern as depicted below (ground level).

[image]

Additionally, the coriolis effect leads to (ground level) winds to the west, similar to earth (earth has three cells per hemisphere, but since this planet rotates slower and for simplicity, it has only one cell per hemisphere - also, I'm assuming the same direction of rotation as earth); see below.

[image]

That would result in an overall pattern like this:

[image]

**H O W E V E R,**
this is not consistent with information I found online.

Most prominent, there is [this paper](https://www.pnas.org/doi/full/10.1073/pnas.1315215111) which looks into ocean currents, but since they are influenced by wind, they seem contrary to the logic above.

[image]

Furthermore, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LifRswfCxFU) explains that the situation is as depicted below and thus coherent with what the research paper suggests.

[image]

**Please help me figure out why my understanding of wind patterns does not match the results of the research paper and the information in the video. Thanks!**